# How to dynamically run some tests in parallel in Pytest 3.0.7

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytest

I am using Pytest 3.0.7 (in Python 2.7) and I need to be able to dynamically run selected tests in parallel without modifying the tests.  Take the example code below:

```
import time
import logging
import pytest

logger = logging.getLogger('test1')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
# File handler
logfh = logging.FileHandler('results.log')
logfh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logfh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(logfh)
# Console handler
logch = logging.StreamHandler()
logch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(logch)

def waste_time(prefix, range_end=5, sleep_time=2):
    logger.info("WASTE TIME")
    for i in range(range_end):
        logger.debug("{}, iteration {} of {}.".format(prefix, i, range_end))
        time.sleep(sleep_time)

def test_test1():
    logger.info("Test1 is starting.")
    waste_time(prefix='TEST 1')
    assert True
    logger.info("Test1 is done.")

def test_test2():
    logger.info("Test2 is starting.")
    waste_time(prefix='TEST 2')
    assert True
    logger.info("Test2 is done.")

def test_test3():
    logger.info("Test3 is starting.")
    waste_time(prefix='TEST 3')
    assert True
    logger.info("Test3 is done.")
```

I need to be able to dynamically decide which, if any, tests to run in parallel.  Sometimes it will be test1 and test2 while test 3 will run serially after.  Sometimes test1 will run followed by tests 2 and 3 in parallel, sometimes I'll run all in parallel, sometimes none, etc.

I don't know the combinations ahead of time and am planing to provide them in a separate config file that I will evaluate with a plugin.

I've been playing with the pytest_generate_tests plugin and trying to inject marks onto my tests, but I haven't found a way to successfully mark a test.  I've been using pytest-xdist as the parallel test runner.

Here's one of my pytest_generate_tests experiments (I'm just trying to get it to skip a test for now).

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if metafunc.definition.name == 'test_test2':
        metafunc.definition.own_markers = [_pytest.mark.Mark(name='skip', args=(), kwargs={})]
        logger.debug("Mark set on test_test2")
```

We have thousands of tests we want to apply this to and I can't modify the test modules.  I wouldn't even know how to if I could.  I have to get this to work dynamically.

Yes I know Python 2.7 is deprecated.  We will transition to 3.0, but there's a lot of code and a rather large organization to move.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You would need to implement your own scheduler for `xdist` that distributes tests by your rules.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to skip a test by setting a marker dynamically with the pytest_collection_finish hook like this:

```
import _pytest.mark

def pytest_collection_finish(session):
    for itm in session.session.items:
        if itm.name == 'test_test2':
            itm.own_markers = [_pytest.mark.Mark(name='skip', args=(), kwargs={})]
```

Now to see if I can apply it to my real problem.

Answer (score 0):

To skip a test you can also do like this

@pytest.mark.skip("Not implemented yet")
def test_hello_world():
......

pytest will not pick it up then.